# Change opacity of an HTML image using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I never created anything in Tampermonkey so I'd appreciate the help.

How would a simple script change the opacity  of the following element to 1? :

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 1171px; left: 452px; -ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)'; filter: alpha(opacity=10); -moz-opacity: 0.1; opacity: 0.1; -khtml-opacity: 0.1; opacity: 0.1; z-index: 19;">
  <a href="https://eggcave.com/gobblers/find?code=l9PCaWSN4Qm2cwoHZMtU7fhLXx8x8j8RPlsu4YpfjSgFHXMvWWqN9mImdY2s5S1lNNaVaB1QD5cHeN3hKQazN4V2XKnje1ffDiLk20BLahA8YuprAjTilLtKDHzLJZAU">
    <img src="https://static.eggcave.com/90by90/gobbler_3.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try problems yourself before asking for a solution. Generally it's a good idea to start with the documentation and then come to StackOverflow if you are stuck.

Comment: @nbwoodward, That's true to a point, but really there is no documentation on how to override someone else's CSS on a dynamically-driven webpage that you don't control. That's kind of what we're slowly building up here on SO. A newbie with this problem would have to know (1) how HTML and CSS control transparency. (2) how to negate or override that CSS after the fact. (3) How Tampermonkey interacts with a web page. (4) How it interacts with a JS-driven page  (5) Optionally, the benefits and syntax of jQuery. ... It can all be a bit much and the best way to learn is often a short, direct example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That HTML isn't enough for real good hooks into the image, and you didn't indicate if the page is javascript (AJAX) driven.  **You may need to link to the target page.** (Or otherwise provide an MCVE.)

Nevertheless, the following complete working script should suffice in most cases:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Be through with see-through pictures
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements ("div[style*=opacity] > a > img[src*='gobbler_']", deOpaqueifyParent);

function deOpaqueifyParent (jNode) {
    var parentNd = jNode.closest ("div");
    parentNd.css ( {
        filter: "",
        "-ms-filter": "",
        "-moz-opacity": "",
        "-khtml-opacity": "",
        opacity: "1",
    } );
}
```

Just change the `@match` line as needed.